# Trying to get pixel data from a set of images and store in one single array

Tags: python, numpy

```
Y = np.zeros((1,m))
X = np.zeros((ROWS*COLS*CHANNELS, m))

for i,image_file in enumerate(train_images):
    if 'cat' in image_file.lower():
        Y[0,i] = 1
    else:
        Y[0,i] = 0
    
    img = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (ROWS, COLS),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    X[0, i] = np.squeeze(img_resized.reshape((ROWS*COLS*CHANNELS,1)))
```

I am trying to get the pixel data from a list of images and store all those values in a single array. Images are 64x64x3. Each image should be represented in a single column in X array.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17808\256590185.py in <module>
     10     img = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
     11     img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (ROWS, COLS),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
---> 12     X[0, i] = np.squeeze(img_resized.reshape((ROWS*COLS*CHANNELS,1)))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X[:, i] = np.squeeze(img_resized.reshape((ROWS*COLS*CHANNELS,1)))
```

Using the : operator, we are able to replace all values in that column.